# overflow:hidden not working with translation in positive direction

Tags: css, overflow, hidden, css-transforms

I came across with a weird thing lately with `overflow: hidden;`. I set it to an element, and then I want to transform the elements in it with `translate()`, when it translates in negative direction it will be hidden, but if I translate in the positive direction, it won't be hidden. In desktop browsers it's not really showing, but you can reach it with a little bit of mouse work. And on mobile it's just scrolls, so that is the worst.

Here is an example showing it: http://cssizer.com/KLHlPShW

Comment: What are we meant to be looking at on that page?

Comment: It seems that on android it works fine, but on iOS I can scroll all the way to the button that has `-webkit-transform: translateX(3212px);`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So I've been working with something similar all day and realized that while I had

`html, body {overflow:hidden; }`

...if I add `position:absolute`, `position:relative` or `position:fixed` to the html and body, it fixes the issue.

Comment: Interesting I will try it out, thanks. I forgot to write here, but I fixed the issue with adding to the translated element `position: fixed`.

Comment: @gerhard it's 2016, and I am having the same issue... Position: fixed - issue resolved. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! position: fixed on "html, body" did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

I wrap everything in a container div with the following code. Explicitly set overflow appropriately in both directions. This keeps the X-axis from scrolling in iOS Safari, even if there are elements translated to the right of the main content area.

But scrolling performance is significantly degraded unless you add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`. It took me a long time to find this! Hopefully it helps someone else.

```
.scrollContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude! Works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, and here is how I fixed it:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">        <!-- defines "boundaries" of content -->
    <div id="content">      <!-- part of it must be hidden -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2; 
}

#content {
    /* Translation code ...*/ 
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0a536vw/4/#&togetherjs=911iUm02sR).

Comment: If I remove the `z-index`es from your fiddle, it behaves the same. I don't think they are necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the above solutions didn't work for me.
In my case it did respect overflow: hidden when used on html.
So for those people with the problem of translate extending the viewport:

```
html {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. No need to set position as in the accepted answer.