# Fitting layout vertically and horizontally without scrolling/overflow

Tags: css

I'm attempting to create a layout where the app takes up 100% of the vertical and horizontal space without any overflow.

Instead this is what it looks like:

https://stoic-snyder-620f18.netlify.app/

Here's the code. Any idea what could be causing all the divs to be larger than they should be? I've been stuck on this for hours, no idea what to do.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import styled, { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import logo_image from "../../static/logo_white_trans.png"
import fb_icon_image from "../../static/fb_icon.png"
import ig_icon_image from "../../static/ig_icon.png"
import yt_icon_image from "../../static/yt_icon.png"

const Global = createGlobalStyle`
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

`

const Layout = () => {
    const [nav, showNav] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div id='app' style={{ height: '100vh', backgroundColor: 'pink', display: 'grid', gridTemplateRows: '15% 70% 15%' }}>
            <Global />
            <div id='header' style={{ height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'blue', display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: '20% 60% 20%' }}>
                <div id='logo' style={{ width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'orange' }} >
                    <img src={logo_image} />
                </div>
                <div id='title' style={{ width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'lime' }}>
                    Title
                </div>
                <div id='menu' style={{ width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'coral' }}>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='content' style={{ height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'teal' }}>
            </div>
            <div id='footer' style={{ height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'grey', textAlign: 'center', marginTop: '0.25rem', marginBottom: '0.25rem' }}>
                <img src={fb_icon_image} style={{ height: '90%', display: 'inline-block' }} />
                <img src={ig_icon_image} style={{ height: '90%', display: 'inline-block', marginLeft: '1rem', marginRight: '1rem' }} />
                <img src={yt_icon_image} style={{ height: '90%', display: 'inline-block' }} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [overflow:hidden not working with translation in positive direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469548/overflowhidden-not-working-with-translation-in-positive-direction)

Comment: It is because of translation you use - just put `html, body {overflow:hidden; }`, or `body {overflow:hidden; }`

Comment: That worked for desktop, but when viewing on mobile I'm getting a lot of extra space even with overflow set to hidden. I think there's something wrong with the header css since that's the part that extends way too far vertically.

Comment: You should [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270084/overflow-xhidden-doesnt-prevent-content-from-overflowing-in-mobile-browsers#answer-14271049).

Comment: Thank you, setting position to fixed corrected the problem.